# SQL: count how many people are on level X from date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called [game].[dbo].[gamer]:

```
name     record_date   date_order   level  
Bob      2023-01-03    1            silver
Bob      2023-01-02    2            silver
Bob      2022-12-31    3            gold
Heidi    2023-01-03    1            brown
Heidi    2023-01-01    2            silver
```

Ex. Heidi was on silver level from 2023-01-01 til 2023-01-02, and was on brown level from 2023-01-03

which means it can be interpret like this: (just show it for you to understand, but it's not a real table)

```
name     record_date               level
Bob      2023-01-03                silver
Bob      2023-01-02                silver
Bob      2023-01-01                gold
Bob      2022-12-31                gold
Heidi    2023-01-03                brown
Heidi    2023-01-02                silver
Heidi    2023-01-01                silver
```

Now I need to count how many people are on level X everyday between 2022-12-30 and 2023-01-03 and insert them into a new table [game].[dbo].[level_count]

My expected result of [game].[dbo].[level_count]:

```
date          level        count
2023-12-31    gold         1
2023-01-01    gold         1  
2023-01-01    silver       1  
2023-01-02    silver       2
2023-01-03    silver       1
2023-01-03    brown        1
```

I do not know how to do it, here's just my thought of how to code, but not sure how it will work:

```
WITH Dates AS (
         SELECT
         [Date] = CONVERT(DATETIME,'2022-12-30')
         UNION ALL SELECT
         [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
         FROM
         Dates
         WHERE
         Date < '2023-01-04'
 )  
 insert into [game].[dbo].[level_count]
 SELECT Date 
 --use Date here to count how many people are on level X that date from [game].[dbo].[gamer]
 FROM Dates
```

Please note:

1. The total rows of [game].[dbo].[gamer] are about 18 million rows, so I want to find an efficient way to do this.
2. My date ranges will actually be 2018-01-01 to 2023-11-13. The scale is large.

Thank you!

Updated: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why do that in the database? Such tasks can usually be much better done for example using a Linq query in your application.

Comment: What about: `SELECT record_date, level, count(*) FROM gamer GROUP BY record_date, level` ?

Comment: @Abra The result will be different than the one I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was prepared independently, but is logically identical to that posted earlier by Adrian Maxwell. Votes should be placed on Adrian's answer. I'll leave this up for reference and comparison.*

Each `gamer` row can be self-joined with another row having `date_order - 1` to determine the effective end-date (exclusive) for each row. A null value would indicate no end.

That can be calculated in a Common Table Expression (CTE) that can be joined with a calendar date range also generated using a recursive CTE. Finally a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` will yield the desired results.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2022-12-30'
DECLARE @ThruDate DATE = '2023-01-03'
DECLARE @EndOfTime DATE = '9999-12-31'

;WITH CTE_Dates AS (
    SELECT @FromDate AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date]) AS [date]
    FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE [date] < @ThruDate
),
CTE_Gamers AS (
    SELECT G.*, G2.record_date AS end_date
    FROM gamer G
    LEFT JOIN gamer G2
        ON G2.name = G.name
        AND G2.date_order = G.date_order - 1
)
SELECT D.[date], G.level, COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM CTE_Dates D
JOIN CTE_Gamers G
    ON G.record_date <= D.[date]
    AND D.[date] < ISNULL(G.end_date, @EndOfTime)
GROUP BY D.[date], G.level
ORDER BY D.[date], G.level
```

The end-date can be also be calculated using the `LEAD()` window function, which eliminates the need for having a `date_order` column.

```
CTE_Gamers AS (
    SELECT G.*,
        LEAD(G.record_date) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY record_date) AS end_date
    FROM gamer G
)
```

Results:

| date | level | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-31 | gold | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | gold | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | silver | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | silver | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | brown | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | silver | 1 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qRkziEWg) for a demo of both.

Comment: I just found that my sql version cannot use "Lead" function, so your code actually solves my problem. I will vote your answer, but you guys are all great. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, will you suggest me to split my date ranges to maybe one year per run? I am not sure if I run 2000 days in my 18-million-row table, My SQL server might crash? Or did I think too much?

Comment: Processing 18 million rows is is just a routine day-in-the-life-of SQL Server. Self-joining 18 million rows to get the end-dates and further joining them against 2000 dates is another story. Might take minutes or hours, depending on how efficiently SQL Server can manage the intermediate results. You might need to be cautious to not maintain a read-lock on the source data if other processes need to update it in real-time. This could be resolved using snapshot isolation. Another approach would be to store intermediate results in temp tables, and add appropriate indexes before the final select.

Comment: ...Breaking the calculation up into shorter date ranges may be tricky, because the result for a particular date may still depend on the level-up record from years prior. If you use temp tables, you may be able to partition the self join operations based on name, perhaps a few 1000 at a time. The first step would be to just run the full query on a test or develop (not production) copy of the database to see what the response is. Then you can determine if it needs rework.

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach below is to create a CTE of days, then form date ranges from the source data using the `LEAD` function and finally join the 2 together so that we have each day, and the level that person has on that day. e.g. to form date ranges:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    record_date, 
    ISNULL(DATEADD(day, -1, LEAD(record_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY record_date)), '9999-12-31') as next_date,
    level
FROM gamer
```

| name | record_date | next_date | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2022-12-31 | 2023-01-01 | gold |
| Bob | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-02 | silver |
| Bob | 2023-01-03 | 9999-12-31 | silver |
| Heidi | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 | silver |
| Heidi | 2023-01-03 | 9999-12-31 | brown |

Then combine with "per day" rows formed in a CTE:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('2022-12-30' AS DATE) AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, dt)
    FROM dates
    WHERE dt < '2023-01-03'
),
gamer_with_next_date AS (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        record_date, 
        ISNULL(DATEADD(day, -1, LEAD(record_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY record_date)), '9999-12-31') as next_date,
        level,
        case when level = 'gold' then 1
             when level = 'silver' then 2
             when level = 'brown' then 3
        end as sorting
    FROM gamer
)
SELECT d.dt, g.level, count(name)
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN gamer_with_next_date g
ON d.dt >= g.record_date AND d.dt <= g.next_date
GROUP BY d.dt, g.level, g.sorting
ORDER BY d.dt, g.sorting;
```

| dt | level | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-30 | *null* | 0 |
| 2022-12-31 | gold | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | gold | 1 |
| 2023-01-01 | silver | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | silver | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | silver | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | brown | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yq2c4ZNp)

Comment: Hi Adrian! I just checked your code on fiddle and tried to run again in my sql server, but it showed "Lead" is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: my current version is SQL server 2008

Comment: Then you should try the answer by TN below who uses a left join as an alternate approach.